# Remove a character in string if it doesn't belong to a group of matching pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex

If I have a string such that it contains many words. I want to remove the closing parenthesis if the word in the string doesn't start with `_`.

Examples input:

```
this is an example to _remove) brackets under certain) conditions.
```

Output:

```
this is an example to _remove) brackets under certain conditions.
```

How can I do that without splitting the words using `re.sub`?

Comment: splitting would probably be faster

Answer (score 6):

`re.sub` accepts a callable as the second parameter, which comes in handy here:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'this is an example to _remove) brackets under certain) conditions.'
>>> re.sub('(\w+)\)', lambda m: m.group(0) if m.group(0).startswith('_') else m.group(1), s)
'this is an example to _remove) brackets under certain conditions.'
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use regex here when a list comprehension can do it.

```
result = ' '.join([word.rstrip(")") if not word.startswith("_") else word
                   for word in words.split(" ")])
```

If you have possible input like:

```
someword))
```

that you want to turn into:

```
someword)
```

Then you'll have to do:

```
result = ' '.join([word[:-1] if word.endswith(")") and not word.startswith("_") else word
                  for word in words.split(" ")])
```

Comment: Hmmm, your call to `re.sub` does nothing to the string in the question when I tried it. Did you check it, did I miss something, or is `words` modified?

Comment: @timgeb urgh no, `)` and `_` are not word characters so `\b` doesn't work the way I think it does (I always think of `\b` as the boundary between `\s` and `\S` when it's actually the boundary between `\w` and `\W`. Removed.

Comment: yeah, you can do it with `r'\b[^\W_]+\)'`, but this does not match strings that end with a `)` and have a `_` somewhere in the middle. So you could use `r'\b[^_\W]\w+\)'` unless I overlooked some special case where that one fails as well.

Comment: @timgeb that would also match `_word)moreletters`

Comment: might want to specify the delimiter to preserve any whitespace

Comment: This is actually 4-5 times faster than a regex if you just index the first and last chars